# Создать многострочный запрос на добавление к SQLite базе

Tags: sqlite, sql

Хочу добавить записи в таблицу при этом проверить есть ли запись с определенными значениями в базе.
Делаю примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO Baza SELECT 'Значение1' AS Поле1 'Значение2' AS Поле2 'Значение3' AS Поле3
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT NULL FROM Baza WHERE (Поле1='Значение1')) LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался?

Comment: А в чём вопрос то? Ваша конструкция не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас просто пропущены запятые между значениями полей, да и конструкция LIMIT здесь лишняя. И вообще лучше бы еще указывать в какие поля вы хотите вставить данные, на всякий случай. Должно быть примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO
     Baza
     (Поле1, Поле2, Поле3)
SELECT
     'Значение1' AS Поле1
     ,'Значение2' AS Поле2
     ,'Значение3' AS Поле3
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS
     (
          SELECT
               NULL
          FROM 
               Baza 
          WHERE 
               Поле1 = 'Значение1'
     )
```